# Is this behaviour of NDArray correct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I feel the behaviour of ndarray object is incorrect. I created one using the line of code below

```
c = np.ones((5,0), dtype=np.int32)
```

Some of the commands and outputs are given below

```
print(c)
[]
c
array([], shape=(5, 0), dtype=int32)
c[0]
array([], dtype=int32)
print(c[0])
[]
```

It's like empty array contains empty array. I can assign values but this value is lost, it doesn't show.

```
print(c)
[]
c.shape
(5, 0)
c[0]=10
print(c)
[]
print(c[0])
[]
```

What does (5,0) array mean? What is the difference between a and c?

```
a = np.ones((5,), dtype=np.int32)
c = np.ones((5,0), dtype=np.int32)
```

I am sorry I am new to Python so my knowledge is very basic.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/47564593/7583919 help you?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to python. There seems to be some misconception about `shape` of an array, in particular the shape of a 1D array ( shapes of the form `(n,)`. You see the shape `(n,)` corresponds to a 1 dimensional numpy array. If you are familiar with linear algebra, then this 1D array is analogous to a row vector. IT IS NOT the same thing as `(n,0)`. What `(n, m)` represents is the shape of a 2D numpy array ( which is analagous to a matrix in linear algebra). Therefore saying an array has a shape `(n,0)` relates to an array with `n` rows but each row would have `0` columns therefore you are returned an empty array. If you do infact want a vector of ones you can type `np.ones((5,))`. Hope it helps. Comment if you require any further help.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [43]: c = np.ones((5,0), dtype=np.int32)                                                                  
In [44]: c                                                                                                   
Out[44]: array([], shape=(5, 0), dtype=int32)
In [45]: c.size                                                                                              
Out[45]: 0
In [46]: np.ones(5).size                                                                                     
Out[46]: 5
```

The size, or number of elements of an array is the product of its shape.  For `c` that `5*0 = 0`.  `c` is a 2d array that contains nothing.

If I try to assign a value to a column of `c` I get an error:

```
In [49]: c[:,0]=10                                                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-7baeeb61be4e> in <module>
----> 1 c[:,0]=10

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0
```

Your assignment:

```
In [51]: c[0] = 10
```

is actually:

```
In [52]: c[0,:] = np.array(10)
```

That works because the `c[0,:].shape` is (0,), and an array with shape () or (1,) can be 'broadcast' to that target.  That's a tricky case of broadcasting.

A more instructive case of assignment to `c` is where we try to assign 2 values:

```
In [57]: c[[0,1],:] = np.array([1,2])                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-9ad1339293df> in <module>
----> 1 c[[0,1],:] = np.array([1,2])

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,0)
```

The source array is 1d with shape (2,).  The target is 2d with shape (2,0).

In general arrays with a 0 in the shape are confusing, and shouldn't be created.  They some sometimes arise when indexing other arrays.  But don't make one `np.zeros((n,0))` except as an experiment.