# Understanding numpy shape

Tags: python, numpy

I'm newbie with Python and also with Numpy.

I have this code:

```
one_array.shape
```

When I run it, I get this output:

```
(20, 48, 240, 240)
```

`one_array` is a Numpy Array that has 20 images.

What do mean the other three numbers in shape output (48, 240, 240)?

Comment: do you mind to share your `one_array` too?

Comment: Are you sure that `one_array` is 1D?

Comment: `one_array` is a 4 dimensional array

Comment: Sorry, `one_array` has 20 images inside.

Comment: I suspect you have 20, 3 band (Red, Green Blue) images with a size of 240x240 pixels (originally)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does numpy ndarray shape do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564495/what-does-numpy-ndarray-shape-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array consist of `20` images, each of them is the size `48X240X240`. Which is odd, I would expect that it will be something like `240X240X3` but for some reason you have way more channels (referring to RGB). ]

So the `shape` function return the size of dimension along each axis (the current shape of the entire array), so in your case there is `(20, 48, 240, 240)`

**Edit:**

As the user said, each image consist of `48` NITFY images of `1` channel which explain the output of `shape`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think is: 20 elements in the array. Each of these elements are a NIFTY image. Each of these NITFY images are: 48 images of 240x240.

Comment: @VansFannel Thanks for the acceptance, I added your comment to my answer in that it will be clearer to one reading the answer

Comment: You are welcome. I have used the program MRIcron to open a T1.nii.gz and check that it has 48 images, 240x240 each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your Numpy Array as a Vector that can be in one dimension, but in your case it looks like it is in dimension 4.
(20, 4, 240, 240) means a big matrix composed of 20 x 4 x 240 x 240 elements.

Answer (score 0):

`one_array.shape == (20, 48, 240, 240)` means that `one_array` is a 4-dimensional array with `20*48*240*240` or  55296000 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you can think of `one_array` as an array with 20 elements, in which is element in another array with shape (48, 240, 240). However, usually is it better to think that `one_array` is a 4 dimensional array, that has a total of 20x48x240x240 = 55296000 elements.